# How remove the first dash in a String with powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I want to remove the first dash of this string XXXXX-080-YYYYT in order to get a string that looks like XXXXX080-YYYYT with Powershell. No matter how long the word is, my goal is to remove the first dash. Please, can you tell me how to remove this dash from my string? . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, provide us with what you tried to do. We are here to help, not to do your work for you. More info about posting questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$string= "XXXXX-080-YYYYT"
$string.Remove($string.IndexOf("-"),1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I wanted.

Comment: I want to remove the first dash of this string XXXXX-080-YYYYT If my string starts with WEBX or DWHS or COGN or CLOT or CLAI, in order to get a string that looks like XXXXX080-YYYYT with Powershell, otherwise I don't remove the dash and I keep XXXXX-080-YYYYT. Regardless of the length of the word, my goal is to remove the first dash